# Postfix or infix form?

Tags: scala

Postfix form is not recommended in Scala at least according to IntelliJ Idea. I think I even have read about it. While infix is recommended. I wonder, what the form is here:

```
val out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream)
out write text  // infix
out flush ()    // postfix or infix?
```

I could have written `out flush()` and it would be postfix form, correct?

However, I could also have done `out flush ()` (pay attention to a white-space)  and it seems to be infix form where `out` is an object, `flush` is a method and `()` - is empty parameter list of type `Unit`- just like `out write text`, but instead of `text` we have `Unit` or ().

Is this postfix or infix form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as style guidance is concerned, neither `out flush()` nor `out flush ()` is postfix - because of the parentheses.  `out flush` would be considered postfix.  the difference is that the scala parser behaves oddly with semicolon inference and postfix operators, as discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-internals/H0G-rapIytc).  By adding the parentheses after flush, you remove the possibility that your statement will be parsed in a way you don't expect.  I would use `out flush()`. Adding parentheses directly after the name of the method is the standard for methods with side effects

Comment: does that mean any postfix call can be made infix by adding empty parentheses?

Comment: Yes, in the sense that matters in Scala and probably IntelliJ - that it will remove the ambiguity that the parser is dealing with.  You can also remove the ambiguity by putting a `.` between the object and its member method, or by putting a `;` at the end of the line.  I think that the `;` approach is still _called_ postfix, but it does remove the danger that your code will be misinterpreted.